# Jekyll - including failing when using custom frontmatter variable

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I have this little layout that just include (or better ***should include***) the specific HTMl and parsing based on the language the post is focused.

```
{% if post.language == "en" %}
{{ post.language }}
{% include reviews.en.html %}
{% else if post.language == "br" %}
{{ post.language }}
{% include reviews.br.html %}
{% endif %}
```

However, even setting the post `language` frontmatter variable as `en`, it includes the `reviews.br.html`, not `review.en.html` as it should be...

Any tips on how to deal with this? I'm using Jekyll 3.1.3

Comment: What is the result of `{{ post.language | inspect }}` ?

Comment: I receive `nil` as response

Comment: Had solved it... Changed `post.language` to `page.language`

Comment: You should have `elsif` instead of `else if` as well.